# Terraform string manipulation remove and add sub-strings

Tags: string, azure, terraform, hcl

I have a sting

`crdemo01.australiaeast.data.azurecr.io`

I want to build the following string from the above one:

`crdemo01-test.australiaeast.data`

The same logic should apply to the following input strings as well:

```
crdemo01.australiasoutheast.data.azurecr.io
crdemo01.azurecr.io
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to remove the `.azurecr.io` part from the input string and append `-test` to the first part of the remaining string.

How can I achieve this in Terraform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [replace](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/replace) twice with regex patterns:

```
> replace(replace("crdemo01.australiaeast.data.azurecr.io","/^[^.]+/","$0-test"),"/.azurecr.io$/","")
"crdemo01-test.australiaeast.data"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is the simplest solution that I included in my code.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of functions that can help with this:

- replace https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/replace
- split  https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/split

```hcl
variable "input" {
  default = "crdemo01.australiaeast.data.azurecr.io"
}

locals {
  remove_str = replace(var.input, ".azurecr.io", "")
  first = split(".", local.remove_str)[0]
  final_str = replace(local.remove_str, local.first, "${local.first}-test")
}

output "data" {
  value = local.final_str
}
```

You can combine all that in one line, but is a nice visual to see the breakdown of the code.

Answer (score 0):

This goal seems to require partitioning the input into three parts:

1. The first domain segment, which will have `-test` added to it.
2. Any additional domain segments prior to the fixed suffix.
3. The fixed suffix `.azurecr.io`

Here's a regular expression pattern that should extract the first two segments as long as the third segment is present:

```
(?P<first>[^\.]+)(?P<remain>\..+)?\.azurecr\.io
```

This uses named capture groups, so if you use it with [Terraform's `regex` function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/regex) then you'll obtain a map of strings with the keys `first` and `remain`, which correspond to the first and second segments I listed above.

Using that pattern, you can achieve the result you described in two steps by first extracting the two relevant parts and then concatenating them back together in a slightly different way:

```
locals {
  parts  = regex("(?P<first>[^\\.]+)(?P<remain>\\..+)?\\.azurecr\\.io", var.input)
  result = "${local.parts.first}-test${local.parts.remain != null ? local.parts.remain : "")}"
}
```

In the last case of `crdemo01.azurecr.io` the `remain` result will be `null` because there isn't any intermediate part, so the conditional expression arranges to treat that as the empty string instead. (A possible variation would be to use `(?P<remain>\\..+|)` -- a dot followed by other characters OR the empty string -- which would then cause `remain` to be `""` when there's no middle part.)

---

Example results from the `regex` call from `terraform console`, in case it's useful to see the intermediate results to understand what's going on here:

```
> regex("(?P<first>[^\\.]+)(?P<remain>\\..+)?\\.azurecr\\.io", "crdemo01.australiaeast.data.azurecr.io")
{
  "first" = "crdemo01"
  "remain" = ".australiaeast.data"
}
> regex("(?P<first>[^\\.]+)(?P<remain>\\..+)?\\.azurecr\\.io", "crdemo01.australiasoutheast.data.azurecr.io")
{
  "first" = "crdemo01"
  "remain" = ".australiasoutheast.data"
}
> regex("(?P<first>[^\\.]+)(?P<remain>\\..+)?\\.azurecr\\.io", "crdemo01.azurecr.io")
{
  "first" = "crdemo01"
  "remain" = tostring(null)
}
```